# Custom Compiler Warnings in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, warnings, compiler-warnings

[Custom Compiler Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings) and
[C#: Create custom warning in Visual Studio if certain method is used in source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968249/c-create-custom-warning-in-visual-studio-if-certain-method-is-used-in-source-co)
haven't helped as they deal with code that is under the author's control.

We are using a 3rd party suite of UI controls (DevExpress) in our software and I want to generate a warning when someone uses `MessageBox.Show("blah");` instead of `XtraMessageBox.Show("blah");`

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of thing can be addressed relatively easily via a custom rule for FxCop/Visual Studio Code Analysis.  If you are using Visual Studio Developer Edition, you will even see the rule failures displayed along-side your compilation warnings and errors in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the information about FXCop Nicole. It seems that this is what I'll be doing.

Answer (score 2):

While there's no way you can do *real* custom compile-time error in .NET, there's a number of third-party tools (both free and commercial) that can inject their validation logic into the build process, usually after the compilation.

Here are three ways I know of to solve you problem:

1. [Resharper 5.0](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2009/10/resharper-50-overview/)($) will support [custom rules](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/structural_search.png) / warnings.
2. In [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/)(free) you can define [OnMethodBoundary](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp.HxS/UserGuide/Laos/AspectKinds/OnMethodBoundaryAspect.html) aspect, overwrite its [CompileTimeValidate](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp.HxS/UserGuide/Laos/Validating.html) method and emit a [post]compile-time error from it.
3. [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) can be integrated with your build process ($) to enforce coding policies like that

Answer (score 1):

No there is no direct way. If you think about it you are looking for a compiler warning for some code that you don't even compile.

If you really want this you could use Reflection methods on YOUR compiled assembly to check if any methods/assemblies you don't want have been called. [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) has a lot of the functionality you need. You could then make this part of your build process.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Cecil. Interesting project.