# Is there any way to stop a method being called at compile-time?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have some classes, which have several methods which I don't really want to be there, but are there simply because the XML Serializer needs them. Is there anyway to generate compile-time errors/warnings if they get called from user-code?

I am aware that I can implement IXmlSerializable, and I am also aware that I can separate out the classes into purely data storage classes, however, I am not asking a question about how I should design such a system, I am simply asking if there is a way to generate compile-time errors/warnings if they are called by anything that is not the XML serializer...

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968249/c-create-custom-warning-in-visual-studio-if-certain-method-is-used-in-source-co

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add

```
[Obsolete]
```

to the method. The [`IsError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.iserror.aspx) property of [`ObsoleteAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) controls whether an error or warning is generated, and you can provide an explanatory message too.

Comment: [Obsolete], serves a different purpose than what OP intends. I don;t think this is the way this attribute is meant to be used.

Comment: @Pop: sure, the purpose is perhaps slightly different, but the result is probably exactly what was asked for.

Comment: Sorry, one further question - is there any way that I can apply something similar to the set mutator of a property, such that you can get the value but not set it, or would the best solution to be to define a separate property, and mark the whole property as obsolete?

Comment: @Matt: I'm not sure, I'm afraid. I suggest you have a play with it :)

Comment: @Matt the targets for ObsoleteAttribute are: AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Event | AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Delegate Wich don't include event an property accesors. The answer is no, you can't add the ObsoleteAttribute to property accessors.

Answer (score 5):

You could decorate the members in question with the [ObsoleteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx). Its intention is a bit different, but it will generate compiler warnings (or errors) when called from user code.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the methods from users intellisense using the [[EditorBrowsable]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) attribute, and from property designer using [[Browsable]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx), attribute.

I don't recommend using the [ObsoleteAttribute], because it conveys a different meaning to what method state actually is. Instead use a comment indicating that the method should not be used from user code.

Also keep in mind that there are lot's of users that compile their code with **threat warnings as errors**, which will make impossible for them to compile **valid** code, in this case.

---

Comment: ObsoleteAttribute conveys a slightly different meaning, but has the desired behaviour. I'd argue that EditorBrowsable doesn't actually have the meaning of "you shouldn't call this from user code" either - and it doesn't generate warnings or errors, which is the desired behaviour in this case.

Comment: Jon's answer is pretty much spot on for me, because I am refactoring some old code, and I don't have the time to completely re-design it right now, so if I can shake out poor object usage patterns with compile time errors, that's a big win for me - certainly not the ideal computer zen amazingness, but a big win none the less.

Comment: @Matt Whitfield +1 for pragmatism